# Set value of an input control using JasperReports Web Services

Tags: php, curl, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using JasperReports Server Web Services to retrieve a report as PDF using php curl.

Unfortunately, the report I want to generate uses a value as **Input Control**

If I don't provide a value to this input control, my report works but every value is 0.

According to the official guide : [JasperReports Server Web Services Guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide_1.pdf) page 24, it says I should use the **IC_GET_QUERY_DATA** argument in the URL so I did it and provided the URI of the data source and then I used **P_param_name** to provide the value of the parameter but I can't get it to work, it seems the report is not using these values.

Thank you in advance for any comment that may help !

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the new run report mechanism (part of the "RESTv2 services"). You can supply input controls for your report as query items in the URL. Multi-select inputs can be defined as many times as you need selections made.

For example, if you send a GET request to http://[yourserver]:[port]/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/uri/to/my_report.pdf?state=CA&state=OK&city=Sacramento

You will get a report where the State control is set to "OK" and "CA", and the City control is set to "Sacramento"

It may be beneficial for you to use the REST [php wrapper](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/php-client) to make these requests more simple.

The same example as above can be achieved like this:

```
$client = new JasperClient('yourserver', 'port', 'username', 'password', '/jasperserver');
$report_data = $client->runReport('/uri/to/my_report', 'pdf', null, null, array('state' => array('OK', 'CA'), 'city' => 'Sacramento'));
```

The binary data of the report will be stored in `$report_data` and you can do with it whatever you wish. (i.e: fwrite to file, stream to browser for download... etc).